Is there a straightforward way to triangulate this tetrahedrally-symmetric convex surface according to these criteria?
I have a tetrahedrally-symmetric surface of constant width defined in spherical coordinates by the support function
$$
h(θ, φ) = \frac{S}{16} ⋅ \left(\sin(θ)^3 ⋅ \cos(3 ⋅ φ) + \frac{5 ⋅ \cos(θ)^3 - 3 ⋅ \cos(θ)}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + \frac{W}{2}
$$
where $W$ and $S$ are non-negative real numbers that adjust the surface's shape.
The surface can be plotted in Cartesian space with the equations
$$
\begin{alignedat}{1}
& x(θ, φ) = \sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ) & \, ⋅ \, h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ) & ⋅ h_θ'(θ, φ) - \frac{\sin(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ'(θ, φ)\\
& y(θ, φ) = \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ) & \, ⋅ \, h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ) & ⋅ h_θ'(θ, φ) + \frac{\cos(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ'(θ, φ)\\
& z(θ, φ) = \cos(θ)           & \, ⋅ \, h(θ, φ) - \sin(θ)           & ⋅ h_θ'(θ, φ)
\end{alignedat}
$$
where $h_θ'(θ, φ)$ and $h_φ'(θ, φ)$ are the partial derivatives of $h(θ, φ)$ with respect to $θ$ and $φ$, respectively.

I want to generate a triangular-mesh approximation of the surface with a few specific properties:

the mesh is composed of flat triangles, each defined by three points which lie on the surface;
the points are defined by linearly interpolating two variables between finite minimum and maximum values;
the angle between the normal vectors of any two points which share an edge is (roughly) constant across the entire mesh, meaning the points are farther apart in less-curved regions and closer together in more-curved regions;
the mesh has full tetrahedral symmetry just like the true surface which it is approximating, so any transformation which would leave a regular tetrahedron unchanged would do the same for the mesh;
there is a point in the center of each "face", "edge", and "vertex" of the tetrahedral shape; and
each point has an antipodal twin that lies along the line which passes through that point in the direction of the normal vector of the surface at that point.

Is there a straightforward way to generate such a mesh?
I would happily accept a parametrization for one or more patches of the mesh which can be copied and transformed by reflection and rotation to build up the complete mesh, so long as the compound-mesh satisfies the above requirements.
The 2D case, where we approximate a smooth curve-of-constant-width with a finite number of straight line segments, is extremely easy with the 2D analog of the above surface-of-constant-width. Given the support function
$$
h(φ) = \frac{S}{16} ⋅ \cos(3 ⋅ φ) + \frac{W}{2}
$$
and the Cartesian equations
$$
x(φ) = \cos(φ) ⋅ h(φ) - \sin(φ) ⋅ h'(φ) \\
y(φ) = \sin(φ) ⋅ h(φ) + \cos(φ) ⋅ h'(φ)
$$
simply taking a linear interpolation of $φ$ in the interval $[0, 2 π)$ with a step size of the form $\frac{π}{3 n}$ for positive integer $n$ will generate a set of points $\left(x\left(\frac{k π}{3 n}\right), y\left(\frac{k π}{3 n}\right)\right)$ which

has perfect equilateral-triangle symmetry,
each have perfect antipodal pairs,
are closer together in more-curved regions and farther apart in less-curved regions,
each have normal vectors at a constant angle with those of their immediate neighbors, and
contains a point at the center of each "edge" and "vertex" of the equilateral triangle.


However, that process does not work in the 3D case, as linear steps along $θ$ and $φ$ produce an asymmetrical mesh, distorted in such a way that I don't see an easy way to cut out a well-behaved patch and copy/transform it to build up the entire surface.
Update
I noticed that the 3D surface contains 4 copies of the 2D curve embedded at various angles in the 3D space:

Adding points along each of those curves in the manner described above gives what looks like a promising first step towards triangulating the surface:

However, I haven't been able to figure out a way to fill in the gaps nicely, or a way to convert the positions of the points-of-one-variable on each of the separate curves into a unified set of points-of-two-variables on the whole surface.

Condition 3 in your list seems to be the crucial one. Since your weird surface is parametrized by points on the unit sphere that are precisely the normal vectors to the weird surface, I suggest you first construct a fine rectangular mesh on the sphere whose curved edges all have equal arc-length on the sphere.
That seems to be the feature that will satisfy condition 3.
The vertices on this mesh then can be mapped by your parametric equations onto the weird surface. The meshes that have this equal-length property are called Chebyshev nets. Surprisingly, they can be constructed (locally) on any smooth surface. An interesting discussion is available here that depicts how to construct such a mesh globally on the sphere. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BFb0054743.pdf
P.S. Chebyshev has an interesting history that you may also enjoy learning about.

The mapping from the sphere to the parametric surface appears to be asymmetrical, at least with the current parametrization, so I'm not sure how well this will work. I'll try and give it a shot and see how the result looks.

Yes, but perhaps you can start with spherical tetrahedral patches, and put Chebyshev nets on each such spherical patch.
