How do I calculate an orthonormal basis, with zero-valued second fundamental form, of a smooth parametric surface at any given point?
Main Question
How do I find an orthonormal basis $X_1$, $X_2$ of tangent vectors at a point $P$ on a surface $S$ such that $I\!I(X_{1}, X_{2}) = I\!I(X_{2}, X_{1}) = 0$, where $I\!I$ is the second fundamental form?
Background and Setup
Given a support function $h(θ, φ)$ and its partial derivatives $h_θ'(θ, φ) = \frac{∂ h}{∂ θ}$ and $h_φ'(θ, φ) = \frac{∂ h}{∂ φ}$ with spherical coordinates $0 ≤ θ ≤ π$ and $0 ≤ φ ≤ 2 π$, the 3D parametric equations for a surface $S(θ, φ) = \bigl(X(θ, φ), Y(θ, φ), Z(θ, φ)\bigr)$ are
$$
\begin{alignat}{3}
X(θ, φ) &= \sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ'(θ, φ) - \frac{\sin(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ'(θ, φ), \\
Y(θ, φ) &= \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) + \cos(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ'(θ, φ) + \frac{\cos(φ)}{\sin(θ)} ⋅ h_φ'(θ, φ), \\
Z(θ, φ) &= \cos(θ)\:& ⋅ &\:h(θ, φ) - \sin(θ)\:& ⋅ &\:h_θ'(θ, φ).
\end{alignat}
$$
Assuming $S$ is a smooth, closed, convex surface (and thus has non-negative curvature everywhere) and given a point $P(u, v) = (X(u, v), Y(u, v), Z(u, v))$ on $S$, I want to find the radii and directions of the principal curvatures of $S$ at $P$ for any values of $u$ and $v$.
I know that the unit normal vector of $S$ at $P(u, v)$ is
$$\vec{n} = \begin{pmatrix}
\sin(u) ⋅ \cos(v), \\
\sin(u) ⋅ \sin(v), \\
\cos(u)
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and the tangent plane to $S$ at $P(u, v)$ is
$$\sin(u) ⋅ \cos(v) ⋅ x + \sin(u) ⋅ \sin(v) ⋅ y + \cos(u) ⋅ z = h(u, v).$$
I also know that the directions of minimum and maximum curvature are always perpendicular to both each other and the normal vector, so finding one direction gives the other.
Wikipedia defines the principal curvature thusly (lightly paraphrased for variable consistency):

Let $S$ be a surface in Euclidean space with second fundamental form $I\!I(X, Y)$. Fix a point $P ∈ S$, and an orthonormal basis $X_1$, $X_2$ of tangent vectors at $P$. Then the principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix
$$
\left[I\!I_{ij}\right] = \begin{bmatrix}
I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) & I\!I(X_{1}, X_{2}) \\
I\!I(X_{2}, X_{1}) & I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are selected so that the matrix $\left[I\!I_{ij}\right]$ is a diagonal matrix, then they are called the principal directions.

@TedShifrin says in a comment "You find the eigenvalues of a $2×2$ matrix $A$ by solving $λ^2 - \operatorname{tr}(A)λ + \operatorname{det}(A) = 0$, where $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ is the sum of the diagonal entries and $\operatorname{det}(A)$ is the determinant." [links added for clarity]
I understand the last line of the Wikipedia definition to mean that $X_1$ and $X_2$ must be such that $I\!I(X_{1}, X_{2}) = I\!I(X_{2}, X_{1}) = 0$. Thus we have
$$
\begin{align}
\operatorname{tr}\left(\left[I\!I_{ij}\right]\right) &= I\!I(X_{1},X_{1}) + I\!I(X_{2},X_{2}), \\
\operatorname{det}\left(\left[I\!I_{ij}\right]\right) &= I\!I(X_{1},X_{1}) × I\!I(X_{2},X_{2}).
\end{align}
$$
Substituting those values into Ted Shifrin's equation and solving for $λ$ with the quadratic formula gives
$$
λ = \frac{I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) + I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2}) ± \sqrt{\left(I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) + I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})\right)^2 - 4 × I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) × I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})}}{2}
$$
Collecting terms and simplifying, I get
$$
λ_+ = \begin{cases}
I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) & : I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2}) ≤ I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) \\
I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2}) & : I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) < I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})
\end{cases} \\
λ_- = \begin{cases}
I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2}) & : I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2}) ≤ I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) \\
I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) & : I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1}) < I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})
\end{cases}
$$
Which means that, regardless of the relative values, the eigenvalues of $\left[I\!I_{ij}\right]$ (and thus the principal curvatures of $S$) are simply $I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1})$ and $I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})$, so long as $I\!I(X_{1}, X_{2}) = I\!I(X_{2}, X_{1}) = 0$ and $X_1$ and $X_2$ are orthogonal unit tangent vectors to $S$.
Thus to get what I want, I need to somehow find $X_1$ and $X_2$ in terms of $u$, $v$, and $h(u, v)$ to get the principal directions at $P(u, v)$, and also evaluate $I\!I(X_{1}, X_{1})$ and $I\!I(X_{2}, X_{2})$ to get the radii of curvature at $P(u, v)$.

Have you looked at some standard differential geometry texts, rather than Wikipedia? Look, for example, at Section 2 of Chapter 2 of my free text, linked in my profile.

@TedShifrin I looked at the linked text, but I can't figure out how to achieve my goal from that. Can you explain how I should go about computing expressions for the principal curvatures?

You don't want the eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{II}$. You want the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathbf I^{-1}\mathbf{II}$. You find the eigenvalues of a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ by solving $\lambda^2 - \text{tr}(A)\lambda + \det(A) = 0$, where $\text{tr}(A)$ is the sum of the diagonal entries and det is the determinant.

@TedShifrin Given that the definition says "$X_1$ and $X_2$ are selected so that the matrix $\left[I!I_{ij}\right]$ is a diagonal matrix", my understanding is that $\operatorname{tr}\left(\left[I!I_{ij}\right]\right) = I!I(X_{1},X_{1}) + I!I(X_{2},X_{2})$ and $\operatorname{det}\left(\left[I!I_{ij}\right]\right) = I!I(X_{1},X_{1}) × I!I(X_{2},X_{2})$. Is that correct (and is that what I should be calculating)?

I reiterate that you want the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $\mathbf I^{-1}\mathbf{II}$ and not of $\mathbf{II}$.

@TedShifrin What does that mean? Can you provide details?

You need the first fundamental form $\mathbf I$, whose entries are typically denoted $E,F,G$. Then you need the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of the matrix $$S=\begin{bmatrix} E&F\F&G\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix} \ell & m \ m & n\end{bmatrix}.$$ Even though the matrices $\mathbf I$ and $\mathbf{II}$ are both symmetric, the matrix $S$ may not be. If $\mathbf I$ is a diagonal matrix with equal diagonal entries, then you can work just with the matrix $\mathbf{II}$, but otherwise not.

@TedShifrin How do I calculate the matrix you call $S$, given my equations for the surface based on its support function $h(θ, φ)$?

There is a simpler way to calculate the principal radii of curvature from the support function of a closed strictly convex surface. You need the formula for the determinant of a $3$-by-$3$ matrix, but that's easy to find. I can provide proofs of the assertions below if you want.
First, use the definition of the support function $$h: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ given in the Wikipedia article you link to. Therefore, we want to write $h$ as a function of $3$ input variables, which I denote below by $(u,v,w)$ (and not $(x,y,z)$), instead of as a function of $2$ input angular variables $\theta$ and $\phi$.
For each $(x,y,z)\in S$, let $(u,v,w)$ be the outer unit normal at $(x,y,z)$. If $S$ is strictly convex, then for each unit vector $(u,v,w)$, there exists a unique $(x,y,z)\in S$ where the outer unit normal is $(u,v,w)$.
Consider the matrix of second order partial derivatives (i.e., the Hessian of $h$),
$$
H(u,v,w) = \begin{bmatrix} \partial^2_{uu}h & \partial^2_{uv}h & \partial^2_{uw}h \\ \partial^2_{vu}h & \partial^2_{vv}h & \partial^2_{vw}h \\ \partial^2_{wu}h & \partial^2_{wv}h & \partial^2_{ww}h \end{bmatrix}. $$
This matrix has 3 eigenvalues. One is $0$. The other two are the radii of curvature of $S$ at $(x,y,z)$. In other words, the cubic polynomial
$$ p(t) = \det (H(u,v,w) - tI) $$
can be factored into
$$ p(t) = t(r_1-t)(r_2-t), $$
where $0, r_1, r_2$ are the eigenvalues of $H(u,v,w)$.
The roots $r_1,r_2$ are the radii of curvature at $(x,y,z)$. Therefore, if you have a formula for $h(u,v,w)$, then you can calculate all of its second order partial derivatives to find the matrix $H(u,v,w)$. You can then use the formula for the determinant of a $3$-by-$3$ matrix to find the polynomial $p(t)$. Since $0$ is a root of $p$, $$p(t) = tq(t), $$ where $q$ is a quadratic polynomial whose roots are the radii of curvature.
Another way is to consider the matrix
$$
\tilde{H} = \begin{bmatrix} u^2 + \partial^2_{uu}h & uv + \partial^2_{uv}h & uw + \partial^2_{uw}h \\ vu+\partial^2_{vu}h & v^2 +\partial^2_{vv}h & vw +\partial^2_{vw}h \\ wu +\partial^2_{wu}h & wv + \partial^2_{wv}h & w^2 + \partial^2_{ww}h \end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then the following holds:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{trace}(\tilde{H}) &= 1 + r_1 + r_2\\
\det(\tilde{H}) &= r_1r_2.
\end{align*}
So you can use the formula for $h(u,v,w)$ to calculate the matrix $\tilde{H}(u,v,w)$. From this you can calculate the trace and determinant of $\tilde{H}$ and solve the equations above for the radii of curvature $r_1, r_2$.

I have a formula for $h(θ, φ)$, but you say I need to convert that to $h(u, v, w)$, so I'm trying to work out how to do that. You also say "For each $(x, y, z) ∈ S$, let $(u, v, w)$ be the outer unit normal at $(x, y, z)$." Since I know that the outward-pointing unit normal vector of $S$ at $P(θ, φ)$ is $\vec{n} = \bigl(\sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ), \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ), \cos(θ)\bigr)$, does that mean I have $u = \sin(θ) ⋅ \cos(φ)$, $v = \sin(θ) ⋅ \sin(φ)$, and $w = \cos(θ)$?

It's a little trickier than that. The formulas you give in the comment hold only when $(u,v,w)$ is a unit vector, but you need a formula for $h$ in terms of any $(u,v,w)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ that matches the Wikipedia definition. If you could provide the formula in terms of $\varphi, \theta$ of a specific support function by either providing a link to one of your earlier questions or as a formula here, I can illustrate.

I just tried this using the support function you posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4908454/is-there-a-straightforward-way-to-triangulate-this-tetrahedrally-symmetric-conve. I can see that although the calculation of $h$ as a function of $(u,v,w)$ and its Hessian is straightforward, the final formula is quite a mess. So the formulas for the principal radii will probably be an even more horrible mess. My guess is that it won't be much better using your approach above. What's your goal here?

My goal is twofold: first, to be able to draw the two osculating circles (for both maximum and minimum curvature) at any point on the surface; second, to be able to define surfaces as the locus/envelope of both centers of curvature across the entire surface. For drawing the surfaces, I need to have a two-input parameterization, as the software I'm using doesn't support three-input surfaces.

In terms of your first goal, you can now do the following: 1) Check my calculation of $\hat{h}$ 2) Calculate the formula for the matrix $H$ 3) Use software to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $H$ for each $(u,v,w)$ 4) This is enough to figure out what the osculating circles are.

As for the second one, your earlier question lists requirements you want for the mesh. I think it is difficult and perhaps even impossible to meet all of these requirements. Perhaps you'll settle for "evenly distributed points on the unit sphere"? Even this is difficult or impossible to do. However, if you google this, you'll find lots of discussion, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/9606368. I particularly like hypercube rejection, since it is very easy to implement.
